# Razor and jQuery, appending the table

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have problem with Razor syntax and jQuery, I'm trying to append some items to an empty table.
Here's the code

```
        @{
            if (@ViewData["a"] != null)
            {
                var tab = @ViewData["a"] as List<string>;
                foreach(var sp in @tab)
                {
                    <text>
                        $('#files-table').append(@Html.Raw(@sp));
                    </text>
                }
            }
        }
```

the `@sp` variable is like (I've formatted it here):

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a class='some-class' my-type='abc' my-id='1'
           target='_blank' href='/Home/a'>name123</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label class='del' f-id='abc'>lorem</label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The table is still empty. I've tried many options, like `.append('@Html.Raw(@sp)')`, `.append(@Html.Raw(sp))` etc but with no success

Comment: What does the resulting HTML look like? Also, are you getting any JS errors during execution?

Comment: the result is the empty table without any `<tr>` rows. I don't get any errors using that code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@` should only be used when you're making a transition between html and code. otherwise, while you're in one or the other you don't need it. With that said, give this a try:

```
@if (ViewData["a"] != null)
{
  var tab = (List<String>)ViewData["a"];
  foreach (var sp in tab)
  {
    <text>
      $('#files-table').append('@Html.Raw(sp)');
    </text>
  }
}
```

---

[Screenshot http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/3250/razordemo.png](http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/3250/razordemo.png)

Note that I also enclosed the result of `Html.Raw` in quotes. You may need to do more to safe-guard that there are no quotes in `sp` that may interfere with the wrapping quotes.

*I have to ask though, that if you have the data up-front and able to be rendered why are you handing it off to the client to render (more error-prone and creating both a latency and a dependancy) and not rendering it yourself? It doesn't seem efficient...*

Comment: using that code I get the error `missing ) after argument list` because the HTML code is not being treated as string ?

Comment: @Tony: Updated my answer, i don't get any parsing errors. There may be something else wrong? Razor, while in the IDE, should give you that background showing that code and HTML were properly parsed.

Answer (score 1):

why are you building your rows in the controller?
Try returning a list of objects with the data you want to show on your table and then build the html table in the view like this:

```
@if (ViewData["a"] != null)
{
   var list = (List<YourObject>)ViewData["a"];
   foreach (YourObject item in list)
   {
      <tr>
        <td>
           <a class='some-class' my-type='abc' my-id='1' target='_blank' href='/Home/a'>@item.name</a>
        </td>
        <td>
           <label class='del' f-id='abc'>@item.phone</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
   }

}
```

Also instead of using ViewData, consider sending you data from controller to view using a custom model.